# Extending proofs to the complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

I'd like to ask a general question and then a more specific question about extending a specific property of the reals to the complex numbers.

What is the general structure of extending a proof to the complex numbers? Logically, in my opinion, the complex numbers should have some holes that just simply don't follow the same ruleset as the reals. However, they always seem to. I'm curious as to what the general process is for extending a proof to include $\mathbb{C}$.

Secondly, I have a more specific question about extending the property that given a collection of open sets $\{G_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$, the union of that set $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$ is open, to $\mathbb{C}$.

So obviously you have the proof in $\mathbb{R}$:

Let $\{G_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a collection of open sets. Also define a set $G = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$. Take any arbitrary $p \in \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$; this certainly implies that $p \in G_\lambda$ for some $\lambda$. Then,

$$\exists V_{\epsilon_\lambda}(p) \subseteq G_\lambda \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda \Rightarrow V_{\epsilon_\lambda}(p) \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$$

and therefore $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}G_\lambda$ is an open set.

But my confusion comes when trying to extend this to $\mathbb{C}$. More specifically, I'd like to show that if $I$ is a set, and for each $i \in I$, $U_i$ is an open subset of complex numbers, then the set

$$\bigcup_{i \in I} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \hspace{2 mm} \vert \hspace{2 mm} \exists i \in I \hspace{2 mm} \textrm{such that} \hspace{2 mm} z \in U_i\}$$

is open. What steps do I need to take to ensure that my proof is true for all complex values?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of an open set in $\mathbb C$? If you have, for some indexing set $I$, an open subset $U_i\subseteq \mathbb C$, for each $i \in I$, then the union $G=\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ is open if for each $p \in G$ there is an open disk $B(p,r)$ centred at $p$ with radius $r>0$ which is contained in $G$. This is just like the case of the real line. In your discussion of that case you do not explain your notation $V_{\epsilon_\lambda}(p)$

Comment: Open ball has the same connotation as epsilon neighborhood (which I denoted as $V_{\epsilon_\lambda}(p)$, where $\epsilon_\lambda$ is just an arbitrary $\epsilon$) right? That's the way it was taught in my class. Anyways, wouldn't we need to prove that the notion itself of an open ball/epsilon neighborhood holds for $z = x + iy \in G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$? I don't really understand how we can just state that the notion of distance even holds in $\mathbb{C}$ the same way that it does for $\mathbb{R}$, as it practically adds a whole new dimension.

Comment: What's your definition of an open set in $\mathbb R$?  I don't think the definition of an open set on $\mathbb C$ is or should be any different.

Comment: Hey @fleablood! It's the metric definition, distance not closeness.

Comment: "But my confusion comes when trying to extend this to C"  Why??? " I'd like to show that if I is a set, and for each i∈I, Ui

is an open subset of complex numbers, then the set

⋃i∈I={z∈C|∃i∈Isuch thatz∈Ui}"  That's the definition of union and it is is exactly the some for any universal set.  You can replace $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb N$ or $\{\text{all elephants in Africa\}$ and the definition of union would be exactly the same.

Comment: "It's the metric definition, distance not closeness."  Um.  so?  Did I ever say otherwise?

Comment: The standard definition of an open ball centred at $p$ with radius $r$ is just $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z-p|<r\}$, where $|z|$ denotes the modulus of a complex number $z$, so that $|z-p|$ is the (Euclidean) distance between $z$ and $p$. Reading $|z-p|<r$ as "the distance from $z$ to $p$ is strictly less than $r$ gives the definition of an open ball in any set with a notion of distance (i.e. a metric space) and so in particular, it gives a definition of an open ball in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @fleablood I don't know why you need to be so hostile. I'm not trying to argue with you, you asked what my definition of open set on $\mathbb{R}$ was, and I was just trying to explain while remaining terse. I never said you stated otherwise, *you* asked what definition I was using.

Comment: @krm2233 thanks so much for your answer. Makes much more sense when you consider the modulus of the number as that's the distance from the origin to the point in the complex plane—don't know why I wasn't thinking of that earlier, I guess I just didn't realize that the absolute value used in the $\mathbb{R}$ version so perfectly translated as to be the modulus in the $\mathbb{C}$ version.

Comment: How is that any different than the definition of open set in complex?

Comment: @robertlewison A set $X$ with a function $d\colon X\times X \to \mathbb R$ is said to be  a metric space if i) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$, ii) $d(x,y)\geq 0$ with equality holding if and only if $x=y$, and iii) for any $x,y,z \in X$ we have $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. Taking $d(x,y)$ to be the distance between $x$ and $y$, for many purposes the set $X$ then has a notion of distance which works "the same way" it does in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @krm2233 Cool. Thanks so much :) Still new to learning/experimenting with $\mathbb{C}$ and non-$\mathbb{R}^1$-type spaces. Your help is encouraging.

Comment: Just to be weird.  Let $X= \{text{all the elephants on the planet}\}$.  Define a metric on $X$ so that $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x$ and $y$ are different elephants and $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x$ and $y$ are the same elephant.  We define a subset $A$ to be open if for every elephant $x$ in $A$ there exists an $r>0$ so that for all elephants with a distance of less than $r$ for the elephant are in $A$.  The any union of open sets of elephants is an open set of elephants.  The proof is *exactly* what you wrote in the body of your text.

Comment: That's correct -- in fact with the distance function you define, any subset of $X$ is open, so that the topology on $X$ is the power set of $X$. This metric is called the "discrete metric", and as you presumably already have realised, you can equip any set with an analogous metric.